# How to output unsigned/signed char or <cstdint> types as integers with << in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, char, cstdint

Background:

I have template stream operators (e.g. `operator << (ostream &, std::vector <T>)`) (that output container elements that may possibly be of some 8-bit integer type, (e.g. `unsigned char`, `int_least8_t`, et cetera).

Problem:

Default is that these types are output as `char` (ASCII).
I only used `char` (or `wchar_t` or whatever) for ASCII variables, never unsigned/signed types.
How do I get these other 8-bit types to always be output as `signed int` / `unsigned int` (numbers) instead, even when the caller doesn't know the type?

First tries:

I have tried (with GCC) for example defining `operator << (ostream &, unsigned char)` with a cast in it (i.e. `stream << static_cast <int> (value)`. That works for `unsigned char` values, but then `uint8_t` still gets output as a `char`.

The same underlying type (i.e. `unsigned/signed char` can not be used in overloads, so I can't define an overload of for example `operator << (ostream &, int_fast8_t)`.

Comment: Can you add some code samples?

Comment: Could you please post some code for us to better understand?

Comment: You're confusing... gah this is too long for a comment. Edit: see my answer below

Comment: Sorry everyone, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that comes to mind is using type traits to define the output type for each type. You would have to declare that for every type by hand. The traits could be defined as a template struct that is specialized for every data-type that has a different output-type than the data-type itself:

```
template< T >
struct output_trait {
    typedef const T & output_type;
}
```

In your operator you write:

```
std::cout << static_cast< output_trait< T >::output_type >( variable ) << std::endl;
```

This will do no cast by default, but for types for which `output_trait` is specialized it will do a cast:

```
template<>
struct output_trait< unsigned char > {
    typedef unsigned int output_type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never have guessed that myself. (The other answers completely missed the part about the template container.)

Comment: (Should be `static_cast< output_trait< T >::output_type >( variable )`)

Comment: +1 - really nice idea. **@stellavortex**: But you should still know what will be the types, that your container will have, to be able to specialize the `output_trait` for each type, as you said - "to know the type beforehand". This question is really confusing and unclear to me. And not only to me, as I see the other answers.

Comment: Kirov, you are wrong there. Did you read Space Cowboy's note, or just the code? The template class is automatic, so all unspecialized versions will use that one. (The typedef should however be `typedef T const & output_type;` instead, to avoid copying.)

Comment: What is the reason that it is not the default behaviour. After all signed char and unsigned char are listed as integer types everywhere. If answer is too big, let me know, i'll start a question.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the actual data held in a variable, with whatever representation you choose for printing it.

Think of it this way: `chars`, `ints`, `doubles`, `longs`, whatevers, they're all just chunks of memory for you to store numbers in. A char is a number between 0 and 255 (or -128 and 127) -- you can choose to represent it as an ASCII character, or as a number, or as stars in the sky with the aid of OpenGL.

If you want to see the number behind the character 'a', just instruct your program to treat that chunk of memory (that for you contains an 'a') as a number. Use casts. Here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

See if that helps!

Comment: `+1` for addressing the underlying confusion of the OP, rather than showing which syntax to use.

Comment: This is not possible from within a template operator, since it would require me to know the type beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you right.. output it like this:

```
std::cout << ( unsigned int )char << '\n';
```

Or more c++ style - use static_cast, for example:

```
int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 97;
    std::cout << static_cast< unsigned int >( a ) << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast< unsigned int >( b ) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

both `std::cout` will print the same: the first one - the ASCII code of `'a'`: `97`, the second one - just the value `97`, stored in b. Both, `a` and `b`, are absolutely the same.

Comment: 10x, anyway xD It would be really nice, if posters explain themselves with examples (:

Comment: It's not easy when you have this kind of question. It happens to all of us: if we were really able to describe with accuracy our problem, we would've already found a solution to it. I ended up answering to see if I could explain a bit further xD

Comment: Yep, you right, but what I meant was, that the poster could say: "for example, if I have stored a value `97` in an unsigned char, how to print it as the number `97`, instead of printing `a`." But you're absolutely right, this is not always possible (y)

Comment: This is not possible from within a template operator, since it would require me to know the type beforehand.

Comment: You've said: `"How do I get these other 8-bit types to **always** be output as signed int / unsigned int (numbers) instead, even when the caller doesn't know the type?"` - you don't need to know the type beforehand. As you want the output to be as `unsigned int`, you don't care what is T. Also, if such conversion is impossible (in case that the container has some user-defined type, for example, that cannot be casted to `unsinged int`), this will be a compile-time error, as templates are instantiated compile-time.

Comment: Kiril, that would only work for unsigned non-long integers. I want my container output operator to output all types that are not 8-bit integers using their normal (or custom) output operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
 uint8_t blah = 65;
 std::cout << static_cast<int>(blah) << "\n";
 return 0;
}
```

> 65

Comment: This is not possible from within a template operator, since it would require me to know the type beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast them before you output them:

```
std::cout << (unsigned int) container[index];
```

Comment: container doesn't mean "string" or array, or sth. It means an object, that contains other objects/vars. So, if you have a struct with two chars inside, you can't output them like this (:. Anyway, I didn't down-vote your answer, as I understood what you mean, but don't mix the terms, please (:

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I just tried to give a minimal, abstract example. When I started writing my answer the other (better!) answers were not there.